# Javascript: How to print input to <div> selected by class?

Tags: javascript, html

Edit: Thanks for the helpful answers so far! I'm still struggling to print the input to the "right" div, though. What am I missing?

Next to the input field, there is an option to select either "left" or "right". Depending on the selection, the input is to be printed eiether left or right on the click of a button. This is what I have - but it only prints to the left, no matter the selection.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.input').val();
        if ($('select').val() == "left"){
            $('div.left').html($('.input').val());
            }
        else {
            $('div.right').html($('.input').val());
            }

        });
    });

    </script>
```

Sorry if this is very basic - I am completely new to JS and jQuery.

---

I'm trying to print input from a form into a div. This is part of the source HTML modify (it's for a university class):

```
            <input type="text" class="input">

            <div class="left">

            </div>
            <div class="right">

            </div>
```

Basically, text is entered into the field, and I need to print this text either to the "left" or the "right" div when a button is clicked.

So far, I have only ever dealt with divs that had IDs, so I used

document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = ($('.input').val());

But what do I do now when I don't have an ID? Unfortunately, changes to the HTML source are not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wanna use jquery or not?

Answer (score 4):

Just use normal selectors, like css and jQuery does.
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
in your case:

```
$('div.left').html($('.input').val());
```

Comment: JQuery is nice and simple but I'd rather use solutions without external dependencies. It's been a long time since selectors are implemented in vanilla js.

Answer (score 2):

As you see there are many ways to do this. You can get elements by [tag name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)...

But the most powerful way is to get it with [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
function save() {
 var input = document.querySelector('input').value;
 document.querySelector('div.left').innerHTML = input;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<button onclick="save()">Save</button>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **plenty** of other ways to target HTML elements, but the one you're looking for in this case is **[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**. Note that this returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, so you'll additionally need to specify the index that you wish to target (starting at `0`). For example, if you want to target the second `<div>` element, you can use 
`document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1]`.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
let button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
let div2 = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    div2.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Output</button>

<br /><br />
<div>Output:</div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have unique class names for each element, `document.getElementsByClassName` can be used. This will return an array of elements containing the class. Since you only have one element with each class name, the first element of the returned array will be your target.

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<button onclick="save()">Save</button>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<script>
function save() {
 var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value;
 document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].innerHTML = input;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many ways to do what you want:-

Write the following in console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

now you can see the total number of div elements used in your current document/page.
You can select one of your choice to work on by using "index number"(as in array index) for that particular div.

Lets say your div having class name = "right" is the 3rd one among the other div elements in your document.
This will be used to access that div element.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("right")[2].innerHTML = "whatever you want to write";
```